# unable to create an issue in jira using testlink

Tags: testlink

Create JIRA Ticket FAILURE => com.atlassian.jira.rpc.exception.RemoteValidationException: {customfield_10000=Component is required.} : [] - serialized issue:a:5:{s:7:"project";s:2:"SC";s:4:"type";i:6;s:7:"summary";s:101:"/Salon Cart/CSC/New User Creation Req_SE_007/SC-21:1 - Executed ON (ISO FORMAT): 2014-05-29 14:39:10";s:11:"description";s:159:"Execution ID: 46 Tester: Preshant Test Plan: SIT Round 1 Build: SIT Round 1 Executed ON (ISO FORMAT): 2014-05-29 14:39:10 Execution Status: passed ";s:9:"issuetype";i:1;}

Can anybody help me out to solve this error?
This occurs when trying to create an issue in testlink.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Jira has its own custom field, the `customfield_10000` field that you are looking at is created by you or the someone in your company to track issues.

When you put in a request to create a issue you should provide the values of custom field in order for Jira to process the field.

Comment: How to Delete the users from testlink1.9.9, and how to reset the passwords if the user forgot the password. and How to configure the SMTP in testlink..could you please tel me.

Comment: hello, well delete users?,

Comment: you can edit users by going to users/roles and then do all your actions with users.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved this issue myself. You need to add a default value to customfield_10000 as part of your SOAP configuration. For example in your case:

```
<!-- Template jirasoapInterface -->
<issuetracker>
<username>YOURUSERNAME</username>
<password>YOURPASSWORD</password>
<uribase>JIRASERVER</uribase>
<uriwsdl>JIRASERVER/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl</uriwsdl>
<uriview>JIRASERVER/browse/</uriview>
<projectkey>JIRAPROJECT</projectkey>
<issuetype>1</issuetype>
<attributes>
<customFieldValues>
    <customField>
      <customfieldId>customfield_10000</customfieldId>
      <values><value>SOME DEFAULT VALUE</value></values>
    </customField>
</customFieldValues>
</attributes>
</issuetracker>
```